# Trouble with 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

I have two apps that use the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider to open Excel files on the same machine. One routine is a c# compiled app that works fine..the other is a non-compiled asp.net app that uses vb code behind that we are trying to re-host that throws '**The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**' errors when opening the Excel file - which appears to me to be bogus since the other app runs fine on the very same machine. I have checked the app pools for both and they appear to be set up identically...they both have 32 bit checked and are using the same .Net framework version. The web.config for both of them has the same connection string with the same options (only difference is the name of the connection)..We even re-installed the dll. I tried copying the dll to the bin folder for the aspnet app, but no luck there either. I would compile the asp.net app, except it uses ColdFusion for part of its output... I am hoping there is someone out there that has run into this particular issue and might have some pointers on where to look to solve this... Or maybe a different direction?